# Constructor in the parent class doesn't assign the value to a private variable

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, constructor, initialization

This is my code and you can also run it from http://cpp.sh/5lsds

```
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;
class X{
private:
    int c;
public:
    X(){}
    X(int b){
    c = 11;
    }
    int getC();
};
class Z:public X{
public:
    Z(int n){
        X(23);
    }
};
int main()
{
    Z z(1);
    cout<<z.getC()<<endl;
    return 0; 
}
int X::getC(){
    return c;
}
```

I need to have `X(){}` line since the child constructor needs to call the parent default constructor.

If you run the program from http://cpp.sh/5lsds you can see that the output is `0` while I expect it to be `11`. Since the `Z` constructor calls `X` constructor with an `int` parameter and it sets the `c` value to `11` but the output is `0`.

Comment: `X(23);` means to create a temporary X which is then immediately destroyed. It has nothing to do with the X sub-part of `*this`

Comment: If you came to C++ from Java background, you better forget all of it.

Answer (score 5):

You should use [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list),

> In the definition of a constructor of a class, member initializer list specifies the initializers for direct and virtual base subobjects and non-static data members.

e.g.

```
Z(int n) : X(23) {}
```

> I need to have `X(){}` line since the child constructor needs to call the parent default constructor.

With member intializer list it's not required again (in this code sample).

For `X(23);` in the body of the constructor, you're just creating a temporary `X`, which has nothing to do with the base subobject `X` of `Z`; Then the default constructor of `X` (i.e. `X::X()`) will be used for it. i.e. it's equivalent with:

```
Z(int n) : X() {  // initialize the base suboject X via X::X()
    X(23);        // create an unnamed temporary via X::X(int)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't invoke the constructor of the base class

```
Z(int n){
    X(23);
}
```

This creates an unnamed temporary X object, and passes 23 to its constructor. It doesn't construct the X sub-object of Z.

In C++, we construct bases and members using the member initializer list syntax:

```
X(int b) :
  c(11)
{}

Z(int n) :
  X(23)
{}
```

The member initializer list syntax is pretty much equivalent to the assignment you do when a simple integer is the constructed member. But beware that more complex sub-objects will be default constructed first, and then have their assignment operator invoked. That could make a substantial (worsening) difference in performance to just specifying them in the member initializer list and constructing once.